# How to choose phase to give a desired Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, optimization, fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

I have a mathematical problem arising from a physics application, which I am sure has been solved before, but I don't know the terminology associated with it.  I am looking for references.  Briefly, the problem is this:

> Given an input function $f$ and a desired output function $g$, find a real-valued function $\phi$ such that the modulus of the Fourier transform $\left|\mathcal{F}\left\{fe^{i\phi}\right\}\right|$ is as close as possible to $|g|$ (with respect to some norm--say $L^2$).

(In my particular case, all functions are defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I doubt that fact matters much.)

In practice, the input function $f$ is an electric field, the phase function $\phi$ is provided by a "spatial light modulator", and the magnitude of the Fourier transform gives the output intensity, which you want to have a specified form.

I'm interested in both abstract results and algorithmic solutions to this problem.

EDIT: [Cross-posted on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322712/how-to-choose-phase-to-give-a-desired-fourier-transform).

Comment: I think you need to specify more constraints on $\theta$. In principle, nothing is stopping me from taking $\theta = -i \log(G f^{-1})$ in which case (avoiding points where $f = 0$ etc) we have $f \exp(i \theta) = G$. If we now take $G$ to be the Fourier transform of $g$ we will have $\mathcal{F}(G) = g$. There might be some work to get the prefactor of $2\pi$ right but that is it.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Yes, the phase $\phi$ should be real-valued.  I have edited this into the question statement for clarity.  Thank you for calling attention to this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a full answer in the linked mathoverflow question.  In short, this problem has been studied many times in many different fields, and goes by the name "[phase retrieval problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_retrieval)".  There are many algorithms for solving it, the most famous being the "[Gerchberg–Saxton algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerchberg%E2%80%93Saxton_algorithm)" or "error reduction algorithm".  However, there are some more accurate algorithms based on the [Monge-Ampere equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation), such as the one described in [this paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/10518/2287454/Solving-the-logarithmic-Monge-Amp%C3%A8re-equation-with-a-RK4-algorithm/10.1117/12.2287454.short?SSO=1).